# When to use BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat?

Tags: wpf, image

I am wondering in what cases I should or must use `BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat` when reading an image into a `BitmapSource` or `BitmapImage`. I suppose that `PreservePixelFormat` could be necessary in some cases when transforming a `BitmapSource` or reading the pixels, editing them and saving the pixels as a new image file.

Would be nice if someone could clarify in which cases `BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat` is necessary or offers an (performance?) advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Remarks in [BitmapCreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions.aspx):

> If PreservePixelFormat is not selected, the PixelFormat of the image
>   is chosen by the system depending on what the system determines will
>   yield the best performance. Enabling this option preserves the file
>   format but may result in lesser performance.

When the option is not set, WPF may decode a bitmap in a format other than that is stored in the source file to optimize performance. The original bitmap may perhaps be encoded as [paletted bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.indexed8.aspx), but WPF may decode it as [32 bits per pixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.pbgra32.aspx) bitmap because the target platform better supports that format.

Comment: Thanks Clemens. Your conclusion is right, but it does not explain in which cases passing PreservePixelFormat would be beneficial or even necessary. But it brought me to my conclusion that passing PreservePixelFormat could be beneficial if the image is not only used on the target system but on other systems (OSes) as well.