# how to stream the image using c# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Web; 
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public MainWindow(Stream stream)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            String path = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg";
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            try
            {
                image.BeginInit();
                image.StreamSource = stream;
                image.EndInit();
                using (Stream bmpStream = System.IO.File.Open(path,System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    Image im = Image.FromStream(bmpStream);
                    //Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("aa.gif", true);
                    //var im = ImageFromStream(bmpStream);
                    grid1.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"im")));
                }
                // return image;
            }

            catch (Exception a)
            {
                // return image;
            }
        }
        public void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        }


     }

}
```

I am using the above code to stream the jpg image as bitmap, and set it into a grid using  c#, but `Image im = Image.FromStream(bmpStream);` shows an error. Can someone please guide me in how to stream the jpg image as bitmap and set into grid?

Comment: so jpg is showing into your output?

Comment: Well, common sense says that a local variable is not reachable via an - btw. badly formed on top - URI. What about reading a tutorial about WPF programming? Total basics level.

Comment: aaah,why you are setting path statically?

Comment: Is this a wild mixture of code-snippets from the web? Looks that way to me ... can you clean this mess up a bit first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way WPF handles and displays images is a bit different from the way WinForms did this.
Most image-displaying "things" need a `ImageSource` and you have to search for the right one to use.
In this case you should be able to use the `BitmapImage` - but the last time I checked this one needs some more care to display the content of a byte-stream correctly.

This snippet shows how you should be able to get this working right `BitmapImage`:

```
private static BitmapImage LoadImage(Stream stream)
{
    // assumes that the streams position is at the beginning
    // for example if you use a memory stream you might need to point it to 0 first
    var image = new BitmapImage();

    image.BeginInit();
    image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit();

    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}
```

As you can see you need to tell the image to use the stream as soon as it loads (or you can get nasty things like `ObjectDisposedException`s.

You can use the returned object as your Image's source property.

So I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
public MainWindow(Stream stream)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    grid1.Background = new ImageBrush(LoadImage(stream));
}
```

Comment: i use this code and i give image.UriSource=new Uri(path) but image not set in grid.what can i do

Comment: you mix up the concepts ... if you just need to display a static file just embed it in your project and use it (you can just drag and drop) - but you asked for a way to get the image out of a stream

Comment: for example look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569561/dynamic-loading-of-images-in-wpf

Comment: sorry for my wrong question i need to stream but how do i gave source image to stream

Comment: what exactly do you mean if you say "i need to stream"? **Use** the stream? (*streaming* is something very different)

Comment: +1, but `image.UriSource = null` is redundant. Also `PreservePixelFormat` should only be set if there is any specific reason. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14419611/1136211).

Comment: Clemens: you are right here (to be honest I just copied this from one of my codebases, where I load raw-image data from a database, the code is quite old and I had some issues back then as well - so I did not double check if anything here is redundant) - thanks for pointing this out to me!